# (toad application) sql - cannot insert multiple records using f5 but f9 is working

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert, toad

I was trying to insert multiple records in a table using TOAD SQL.

When pressing F9 it is working, but it only inserts one value at a time.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE3','VALUE4','VALUE5','VALUE6', null);
```

When pressing f5 it says it has inserted but when validating the table, it has not inserted the values I needed.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE3','VALUE4','VALUE5','VALUE6', null);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE3','VALUE4','VALUE5','VALUE6', null);
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN IN ('VALUE1');
```

--no rows selected

Is this an application problem? Or grant access? 
This is the same with all the DML.

Using SQL Developer Application, it has no problem, I can do multiple insert.

I want to continue using TOAD. Please help.
Thanks guys!

Comment: please avoid using capital letters in your title

Comment: F5 executes a (current) statement (the one where cursor currently is), F9 executes a script. If TOAD says that it *inserted* 1 row, then it really did it. Are you checking it in the same session? If not, did you commit?

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, yes I did commit it, and it is in the same session.

Comment: Hm, this sounds strange. I use TOAD *for ages*, no such problems.

Comment: This question is tagged "mysql" but it looks like you might be using Toad for Oracle. If so, check that your connection is running in the same as you think. In Toad's Options, on the Oracle|Transactions page, there is an option to "Execute scripts in Toad session." If this is unchecked then your commit will need to be part of the script if it is not already. Clicking Commit on the toolbar may not do it.